# How to set custom format of cell with trailing text as hr/hrs.?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

Is it possible to set the custom format of cell if the number is 1.0 as "1.0 **hr** " and if the cell is having number greater than 1 the format display as **"hrs"** instead of "hr"?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
[=1]#.0 "hr";[>1]#.0 "hrs"
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer.